# Correct way to write list of json to file in Python

Tags: python, json

Using `Python`, I'm pulling json data from an API - every time I get a response, I add it to a list named api_responses like so:

```
api_responses = [{'id':'1', 'first_name':'John', 'last_name':'Smith'},{'id':'2', 'first_name':'Chris', 'last_name':'Clark'}]
```

I need to write the records to a file so that it's only the records and not a list:

api_responses.json:

```
{'id':'1', 'first_name':'John', 'last_name':'Smith'}
{'id':'2', 'first_name':'Chris', 'last_name':'Clark'}
```

I could for-loop the list, write each row and add '\n'.

```
with open('api_responses.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for response in api_responses:
        json.dump(response, outfile)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

I don't want to indent or pretty the json - just make it flat as possible. Is there a better way to do this? Is `jsonl`/`jsonlines` what I am searching for?

Comment: You should know (if you don't already) that your desired output wouldn't be considered valid JSON and would be somewhat difficult to read back in and parse with any JSON spec-compliant parser. Similarly, it will be somewhat difficult to get a JSON serializer to generate non-spec-compliant JSON out of the box.

Comment: @esqew Thanks - my use case is to load into a database and this format was the only way I got it to work. Is `json.dump` with the entire list the standard approach?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. I'm curious - what database platform accepts invalid JSON files for import?

Comment: "I need to write the records to a file so that it's only the records and not a list" Then that isn't the JSON format. "Is jsonl/jsonlines what I am searching for" Well, did you try using them? Did they solve the problem? Were you satisfied with the result? I don't understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: @LuisFelipe Your answer is not in fact correct and does not at all do what OP needs it to do (the way Python represents objects has nothing to do with JSON); and casting aspersions is not helpful.

Comment: my answer prints into a text file, the output he needs for database reading operation. As far as I can understand the question, the final objetive is the flat text on a file

Comment: Yes, it prints into a text file. The thing that it prints into a text file is **not correct**. The objective is flat text *in a specific format, which differs from your output*. In particular, the output **must** use double quotes if it has *anything at all to do with* JSON, OP's output sample notwithstanding.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I can't see the diference. I am seegint the exact same characters. Why do not wait to OP to say if this is an answer valid or not?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel read in comments, OP says that he knows that is invalid JSON, the only way that his DB reads a file is like he wrote on questino

Comment: As far as I can tell, *each individual line* is still intended to be JSON. That is [*a known, commonly-used, documented format*](https://jsonlines.org/), after all. If for some reason OP needs some other custom thing, then that is OP's burden to determine and explain, and *attempts to answer the question should not be made, per policy, until that is clarified*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Good catch. I missed the fact that the OP makes clear of his intention with the mention of `jsonl` and went along with his expected output when I discussed with Luis about his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code already correctly outputs the JSON objects as individual lines into a file, also known as JSONL as you pointed out.

To make the code slightly more concise and readable, you can take advantage of the `print` function, which outputs a newline character for you by default:

```
with open('api_responses.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for response in api_responses:
        print(json.dumps(response), file=outfile)
```

With your sample input, this outputs:

```
{"id": "1", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"}
{"id": "2", "first_name": "Chris", "last_name": "Clark"}
```

Answer (score -5):

You are looking for the `*` decorator for `lists` on `print`:

```
>>> api_responses = [{'id':'1', 'first_name':'John', 'last_name':'Smith'}, 
                     {'id':'2', 'first_name':'Chris', 'last_name':'Clark'}]
>>> print(*api_responses,sep="\n", file=open('filename.txt','w'))
    {'id': '1', 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith'}
    {'id': '2', 'first_name': 'Chris', 'last_name': 'Clark'}
```

Note that this answer solves perfectly what OP is asking. Open the file `filename.txt` and see that matches with op requests.

**Note:** request is to use simple quote `'`, and this answer match the requierement.

Comment: Reposting your answer and maintaining your incorrect assertion is not how the site is supposed to be used.

Comment: Marking this as incorrect answer is only your personal opinion. I see the exact characters on the output and in the question. You can try it on console and then seeing the text file generated. You should wait to OP to say if this si correct or not